# How to return rows in table1 not present in table2 in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

I have tried using join table in laravel

role_user table has the roles_id and the user_id column
roles table has the id and the name of the role
users table has the id and the name of the user

```
 $roles = Role::leftJoin('role_user', 'roles.id', '!=' , 'role_user.role_id')
        ->select('roles.*', 'role_user.user_id', 'role_user.role_id')
        ->where('role_user.user_id','=',$name)
        ->get();
```

But it seems that `'!='` is not working I have tried using the `'='` and it's just working fine
When im trying to use the `'='` there are no results

I have also tried

```
public function roles()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

@foreach($user->roles as $role)
    {{ roles->name}}
@endForeach
```

But it displays the matching id of user_role and role table, I want to do the opposite i want to display the role table's rows that do not match the user_role's table

Comment: Could you please undelete and accept the answer of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41646784/6309? That will help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display the role table's rows that do not match the `user_role` table

Use [`whereDoesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method:

```
 $roles = Role::whereDoesntHave('users', function($q) use($name) {
     $q->where('name', $name);
 })->get();
```

In the view:

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    {{ role->name }}
@endforeach
```

Don't forget to define `users()` relationship:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Comment: It working now but I don't understand how it works can you kindly explain it to me?

Comment: `whereDoesntHave()` is a method which is checking for relationship absence. So here it gets all roles which doesn't have users with name = `$name`

Answer (score 0):

In your User Model create function roles

```
Role::whereNotIn('id',function($query){
            $query->select('role_id')->from('role_user');
        })->get();
```

Comment: Yes it will return roles on specific user but what i want to display is the rows on Roles table which are not in the role_user's table